# Refactor similar controllers in different modules

Tags: angularjs, code-duplication

My Application depends on multiple AngularJS modules but each module has to deal with similar data. The modules are used in different places on my page.

I've created a bunch of controllers which are basically responsible for assigning data to $scope variables. I think there is a lot of "code smell" in there and i have bad feelings with all the duplicated code. But currently i've no idea how to prevent it.

The Attributes `documentations` and `infomaterial` are resolved and injected in my `$routeProvider`.

What is a better way to deal with such cases?

### Controller 1

```
angular.module('MyApp.selectorDocumentations')
    .controller('SelectorDocumentationsCtrl', function ($scope, FacetService, Attributes, documentations) {

        $scope.documentationsData = documentations.data;
        $scope.documentations = documentations.data.hitlist.content;

        $scope.currentPage = documentations.data.hitlist.page.number;
        $scope.totalPages = documentations.data.hitlist.page.totalPages;
        $scope.hitlistContent = documentations.data.hitlist.content;
        $scope.totalElements = documentations.data.hitlist.page.totalElements;

        FacetService.prepare(documentations.data);

        $scope.hardReset = function () {
            FacetService.hardReset(false, documentations.data);
        };

        $scope.manufacturer = function (item) {
            return Attributes.getManufacturer(item);
        };

        $scope.project = function (item) {
            return Attributes.getProject(item);
        };

        $scope.projectBookVersion = function (item) {
            return Attributes.getProjectBookVersion(item);
        };
    });
```

### Controller 2

```
angular.module('MyApp.selectorInfomaterial')
    .controller('SelectorInfomaterialCtrl', function ($scope, FacetService, Attributes, infomaterial) {

    $scope.informaterialData = infomaterial.data;
    $scope.infomaterials = infomaterial.data.hitlist.content;

    $scope.currentPage = infomaterial.data.hitlist.page.number;
    $scope.totalPages = infomaterial.data.hitlist.page.totalPages;
    $scope.hitlistContent = infomaterial.data.hitlist.content;
    $scope.totalElements = infomaterial.data.hitlist.page.totalElements;

    FacetService.prepare(infomaterial.data);

    $scope.hardReset = function () {
        FacetService.hardReset(false, infomaterial.data);
    };

    $scope.mediaType = function (item) {
        return Attributes.getMediaType(item);
    };

    $scope.mediaTitle = function (item) {
        return Attributes.getMediaTitle(item);
    };

    $scope.mediaSubline = function (item) {
        return Attributes.getMediaSubline(item);
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, those controllers are basically identical. I'd move all that code into a factory, and initialize it with either documentation or infomaterial.

```
app.controller('SelectorDocumentationsCtrl', function ($scope, documentations, MyDataHandler) {
  $scope.myDataHandler = new MyDataHandler(documentations);      
});


app.controller('SelectorInfomaterialCtrl', function ($scope, infomaterial, MyDataHandler) {
  $scope.myDataHandler = new MyDataHandler(informaterial);
});
```

Those could be initialized in a state in `ui-router` also. If you need help to build the factory/service, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer! I do not use `ui-router`. I thought about to move the code to a factory but i'm not sure where have to initialize my `$scope`-Variables like `$scope.currentPage`. To write `$scope.currentPage = $scope.myDataHandler.currentPage` seems not to be an improvement, don't you think?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer per se, but be careful about generalizing this kind of thing.  If you need to modify the code for one of the two use cases, it can get ugly very quickly, and it's harder to separate than it is to combine.  If these two controllers will need to evolve independently, it's better to keep them distinct.

Comment: @PhilSandler I agree, but I think it might be too early to worry about that issue, unless he has big plans to expand those in the short term.

Comment: @PhilSandler actually, I looked at it again, some methods are different. @gearsdigital, maybe create 2 separate services that use the same base `MyDataHandler` (or whatever you wanna call it)